# Backbone.js - get request object inside model or view or collection?

Tags: backbone.js

Is there a way to get the http request object from a model or view or collection in backbone.js?

I am able to store session through node server.js and the server.js is something I used with express. I want to do something like req.session from my backbone js code inside those component.

Comment: Sessions are server-side, but you can pass jQuery ajax options to `fetch`. I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do though.

Comment: Are you trying to get the http request that the server returned after a request?

Comment: Sorry I'm still new to this and I pretty much just copy/modify from the internet. I've a server running "node server.js" and inside it uses express to create session. I can add/get session inside the server.js but once the client backbone js code loaded into user's browser can I still get those session data through backbone code?

Comment: The issue is I've an api running separately then I've the app(backbone) loading through node server.js with session enabled. I want to add/get session from backbone code to use username/password so I can pass it when I do api call. That's why I wonder if I can do it through backbone without doing an extra call to get session data before api call?

Comment: Are you using Backbone server side or client side? In either case a minimal example code would be fine to talk about. If on the client side: you cannot access `request` directly. What exactly do you want to access on the `request` object (data, attributes, cookies, ...)?